# how to use rxjs debounceTime in react native textInput

Tags: javascript, angularjs, react-native, rxjs

I am trying to replicate the `debounceTime` functionality from rxjs. I saw this example from Angular:

```js
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        map(event => event.target.value),
        debounceTime(400),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
      )
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

My replication in react native:

```js
export default function SearchScreen() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  function onChangeHandler(event) {
    of(event)
      .pipe(
        map(event => event.nativeEvent.text),
        debounceTime(400),
      )
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          value={text}
          onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

But I could not find a way to use `fromEvent`. Instead I used the `of`.
But the `debounceTime` is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace changeHandler with a `Subject` and remove `onChangeText` and `value` attributes

```
export default function SearchScreen() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const changeHandler=new Subject()
  changeHandler.asObservable()
      .pipe(
        map(event => event.nativeEvent.text),
        debounceTime(400),
      )
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
  
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <TextInput
          onChange={evt=>changeHandler.next(evt)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code. It gave me the same behavior. Although I type very quickly, all the characters are shown in the console, meaning that the denouncing is not working

Comment: Very strange it should work as expected. If you want creat a simple stackbliz I can help u debug

Comment: It's not possible to create react native app on stackbliz. Should I create one on Snack ?

Comment: You can debug the code here: https://snack.expo.io/@ghasemikasra39/rxjs

Comment: remove     these attributes ```      value={text}
          onChangeText={text => setText(text)} ```  they will render your component 
and changeHandler is recreated as you type. That's why it's not working properly

Comment: Worked perfectly. please update your solution so that I can mark it as the correct answer